# Summation with Multiple Indices

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How would the following summation work?

$\sum_{r,s,t \ge 0_{r+s+t=n}} \binom{m_1}{r} \binom{m_2}{s} \binom{m_3}{t}$

How would you choose the value for the next integer in the series?

For example, for n=2. Either r,s, or t = 2. Or r = 1 and s = 1 (or any combination thereof)

I think the inclusion-exclusion principle would be used but I'm don't know how it would be applied.

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I wasn't sure how to word it.

Answer (score 1):

The more general formula for a sum is the following:
$$S=\sum_{i\in A} f(i) $$
where $A$ is a set and $f:A\to \Bbb N$ is a function. For example in your case :
$$A=\left\{(r,s,t)\big/r,s,t\geq 0,r+s+f=n\right\}\ \text{ and }\ \ f(r,s,t)=\binom{m_1}{r} \binom{m_2}{s} \binom{m_3}{t} $$
How to compute the sum manually, first you determine the set $A$ and then you comute $S$, for exemple if $A=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ then $$S=f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$$
The order of the elements is not important when you compute the sum and does not affect either it's value because the $A$ does not contain any order, so you choose the order you want. The most important here is to determine the completely the set $A$.

---

**Evaluation of the sum**

What is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$(1+x)^{m_1+m_2+m_3}=(1+x)^{m_1}(1+x)^{m_2}(1+x)^{m_3}$$
As consequence your sum equals:
$$\dbinom{m_1+m_2+m_3}{n} $$

Comment: Although this answers the question of what the summation simplifies to, I feel as though the question being asked is instead about the less common uses of summation notation such as $\sum\limits_{\Delta\subset [n]~\text{s.t.}~|\Delta|=r}$ or $\sum\limits_{i<j<k}^n$ etc...

Answer (score 0):

If your question was specifically about simplifying this particular sum, see Elaqqad's answer for a combinatorial argument on what it is equal to.  If your question is more about how to manually compute the sum and how to interpret the notation, then continue reading mine.

[Capital Sigma Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) can have several different ways of writing what the set of values you sum over are.

In this case, for the summation: $\sum\limits_{r,s,t\geq 0~\text{s.t.}~r+s+t=n}$, I interpret it as summing the expression over all possible $r,s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the following conditions hold:

$$\begin{cases} r\geq 0\\ s\geq 0 \\ t\geq 0\\ r+s+t=n\end{cases}$$

In particular, there will be $\binom{n+2}{n}$ summands (seen from stars&bars).  It doesn't matter in what way you choose to add the terms together (since there are a finite number of terms and addition is commutative), though if you wanted to do it by hand I would recommend [Lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (a.k.a. Dictionary Order).

You would do it as: $(0,0,n), (0,1,n-1), (0,2,n-2), \dots, (0,n,0), (1,0,n-1), (1,1,n-2),\dots, (n-1,0,1), (n-1,1,0), (n,0,0)$

where you order the entries according to the the size of the earliest difference.

For an explicit example, with $n=2$ you would have

$$\binom{m_1}{0}\binom{m_2}{0}\binom{m_3}{2} + \binom{m_1}{0}\binom{m_2}{1}\binom{m_3}{1} + \binom{m_1}{0}\binom{m_2}{2}\binom{m_3}{0} + \binom{m_1}{1}\binom{m_2}{0}\binom{m_3}{1} + \binom{m_1}{1}\binom{m_2}{1}\binom{m_3}{0} + \binom{m_1}{2}\binom{m_2}{0}\binom{m_3}{0}$$